# How do I allow msi installers to install older versions over newer ones?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I'm setting up an automatic deployment scheme. It would be really handy for us if we could put older msis on the server and have all the clients roll back to previous versions if one of our new releases turns out to be too bug riddled.

Right now, the msi is bitching at me "Unable to install because a newer version of this product is already installed". What kind of property can I set to turn this behavior off? I will gladly do so in my post build vb script.

Thanks

Isaac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing the DetectNewerInstalledVersion property to false.

It doesn't bitch anymore about this.

Now, with the script that sets the REINSTALLMODE to amus and this setting, my msi will overwrite anything regardless of version.

Answer (score 2):

- Are you using a group policy on your
  domain to deploy the msi?
- Do you have
  a setup project for your msi in
  Visual Studio?

Anyhow, I see a solution but not sure if that's right for you...

You need the code matching the old msi that you want to deploy back.

1. Open the solution matching the code of the old msi.
2. Using `<F4>`, open the properties window of the setup project matching the msi,
3. Increment the *Version* to a higher number then the one currently deployed. It will ask if you want to change the product code, click Yes.

[image]

4. Rebuild the setup project then deploy.

Since the built msi has a higher version number, it will update the one deployed.

Comment: and no, i'm not using group policy. I'm just hosting the msi on a website along with a webservice that gets its version #.

Comment: This would work though, again, I just want something a little more maintainable.

Comment: Damn, I'm afraid that they will have to uninstall the msi first. To force them to uninstall prior to install any newer version of the msi set the RemovePreviousVersion property (setup project) to False.